DNS reply returned 'no error' for list.dnswl.org while 'no records with this name' was expected
I get messages like this, but there is most likely no DNS spoofing and I use the DNS servers from the provider:
monitored; rspamd_monitored_dns_cb: DNS reply returned 'no error' for list.dnswl.org while 'no records with this name' was expected when querying for '1.0.0.127.list.dnswl.org'(likely DNS spoofing or BL internal issues)

I'm not sure if this is due a misconfiguration, if this is a real problem or if I can ignore it. What should I do?

The problem is that dnswl.org only allows limited queries from a DNS server without paying for it. This means in particular that users of a large provider or a free server such as 1.1.1.1 or 9.9.9.9 will be rejected with the above-mentioned message.
What to do about it:

register (for free) at https://www.dnswl.org/ and declare your own domains; and
install your own DNS recursor like https://www.nlnetlabs.nl/projects/unbound/about/

